# Python subprocess & Poetry cutted/shortened stdout

Tags: python, python-poetry

Since the *requiremtns.txt* files from [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org) are hard to read, I try to write a simple script that creates the *requiremtns.txt* file but also at the same time creates a more human readable file next to it. A fitting Poetry command is:

```
~$ poetry show
```

OK..., so I start my subprocess to execute this:

```python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).parent
    # CMD
    package_list = subprocess.run(['poetry', 'show'], cwd=PROJECT_DIR, encoding='utf_8', capture_output=True)
    # Powershell
    # package_list = subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', '-Command', 'poetry', 'show'], cwd=PROJECT_DIR, encoding='utf_8', capture_output=True)
    print(package_list.stdout)
```

Only problem is, I get this "cutted" content:

```
alabaster                       0.7.16          A light, configurable Sphin...
argon2-cffi                     23.1.0          Argon2 for Python
argon2-cffi-bindings            21.2.0          Low-level CFFI bindings for...
asgiref                         3.7.2           ASGI specs, helper code, an...
attrs                           23.2.0          Classes Without Boilerplate
autopep8                        2.0.4           A tool that automatically f...
babel                           2.14.0          Internationalization utilities
certifi                         2023.11.17      Python package for providin...
cffi                            1.16.0          Foreign Function Interface ...
charset-normalizer              3.3.2           The Real First Universal Ch...
colorama                        0.4.6           Cross-platform colored term...
concurrent-log-handler          0.9.25          RotatingFileHandler replace...
cryptography                    41.0.7          cryptography is a package w...
django                          5.0.1           A high-level Python web fra...
django-cors-headers             4.3.1           django-cors-headers is a Dj...
django-cprofile-middleware      1.0.5           Easily add cProfile profili...
django-rest-knox                4.2.0           Authentication for django r...
django-silk                     5.1.0           Silky smooth profiling for ...
django-stubs                    4.2.7           Mypy stubs for Django
django-stubs-ext                4.2.7           Monkey-patching and extensi...
djangorestframework             3.14.0          Web APIs for Django, made e...
djangorestframework-dataclasses 1.3.1           A dataclasses serializer fo...
djangorestframework-stubs       3.14.5          PEP-484 stubs for django-re...
docutils                        0.20.1          Docutils -- Python Document...
drf-spectacular                 0.27.1          Sane and flexible OpenAPI 3...
```

As you can see, I already tried using Powershell, since I thought it's a CMD problem, but result stays the same. I also tried rerouting `stdout` directly into a file. Still the same. I also tried unbuffered version (`bufsize=0`), still the same...

**Now the question:** What do I need to do, to get the "full" text, like you get if you enter `poetry show` in your terminal?

### Update

I have now tried this on an Ubuntu OS. The result is the same, therefore this is **NOT** Windows specific.

Comment: Strange... If I were you I would try the `--verbose` flag (can be added up to three times).

Comment: I also tried that one in all 3 variants: `-v`, `-vv`. `-vvv`. Result is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inspecting the source code, I can see that poetry [unconditionally limits the output of `poetry show` to the current terminal's width](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/685fd2c1eccfb98153e269ed1d0072ccb5941fc7/src/poetry/console/commands/show.py#L383), so even when running the command manually you won't always get the full description of each package:

```py
width = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns

...

if len(locked.description) > remaining:
    description = description[: remaining - 3] + "..."
```

The documentation for `shutil.get_terminal_size` says it defaults to 80 columns if not connected to a terminal (which is the case when you set `capture_output=True` using `subprocess.run`), which explains why your output is truncated. The documentation says that it uses the value from the environment variable `COLUMNS` if set, so one solution is to set that to a very large value in your subprocess invocation:

```py
subprocess.run(['poetry', 'show'], capture_output=True, env={'COLUMNS': '9999'})
```

This isn't ideal because there's no guarantee of how long any given output line may be (though 9999 characters seems like a safe number); a more robust approach would be to parse `poetry.lock` (or pyproject.toml depending on your needs), since it doesn't look like the output of `poetry show` is really meant to be machine-readable:

```py
import tomllib

with open('poetry.lock', 'rb') as lockf:
    lock = tomllib.load(lockf)

for package in lock['package']:
    print(package['name'], package['version'], package['description'])
```

This won't work if you want to use information that Poetry computes itself (like the output from `poetry show --outdated`), but generally works better than running a subprocess if you don't need any more information than regular `poetry show` gives you.

Comment: Very nice explanation. I stayed with the simple "9999" solution although i reduced it to 1000, since the description should be a one-liner: [https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/#description](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/#description)